# Excel and C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vba

I'm currently developing a C # application which currently uses a VBA macro in an Excel perform data extractions.

The Excel file is essential to achieve the extraction of data and this file will be located on the customer's computer. As this code is private content and has an intellectual property law, I wanted to know how I can deploy to my customers VBA code while protecting the code?

I heard about VSTO, is it possible to run VBA code from a VSTO plugin? It is correct security level?

Thank you

Comment: atleast show something you have tried (code)

Comment: My VBA code is already working and he's about 100 150 lines. But i dont know how to deploy it on customer's PC because XLA file protection is weak...

Answer (score 0):

If your going to create a VSTO plug in then why is the VBA needed? You can just manipulate the data directly from your C# code as per the following link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668205.aspx

If the point of the application is to export data from the database, why not use a library such as EPPlus and just export the code from an external application? Again, no VBA code for someone to potentially see.

Either way, your code is not in the public domain of a standard user. If your really concerned about your code being high jacked, it is worth reading up on Obfuscation too

Comment: Can you send me a name of VBA Obfuscation tool? Currently i'm using Dotfuscator to obfuscate my C# code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to know how I can deploy to my customers VBA code while
>   protecting the code?

Excel provides a mechanism to lock access to the macro source code any workbook which I assume you know about. E.g. see [here](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/protect-macro.html).

> I heard about VSTO, is it possible to run VBA code from a VSTO plugin?

[Yes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608614.aspx)

> It is correct security level?

The VBA security has nothing to do with how you call it. If a macro is protected than it will stay protected no matter how you call it. To say it another way, calling a macro from VSTO does not protect it in any way.

If you want to "hide" a function from the user simply protect the project and mark the function as private. But even if the function is public the user can't see the source.